# Sass DevTools wrong path and line

Tags: sass, gruntjs, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I want to edit sass files for my project using google devtools.
After adding my project from the workspace, I can make live changes.
But..
The source map shows the path to the sass files incorrectly.
as seen in the links.
the selector does not point to the right place.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxGOW.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivTsp.jpg

where did I make a mistake?

**EDIT:
I solved the problem myself :)
cache and cookies cleared.**

Comment: we would like to help you but make your question easier to understand and follow these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask